# Regression without known covariates: approximating the likelihood

Tags: regression, missing-data, likelihood, approximation

I would like to perform (linear) regression for an outcome $y$ but do not have access to the covariates $x$. Instead, each record $i$ belongs to one of $K$ groups and I know the distribution of $x_i$ conditional on the group membership $g_i$. I have considered two different approximations for the likelihood of my data giving different results but I do not understand why one should be preferable to the other.

## Method 1 (works but makes stronger assumptions)

I would like to approximate the likelihood of the outcomes $y$ conditional on the regression coefficients $\theta$, and the group memberships $g$. The covariates $x$ are latent. The likelihood is

$$
L\equiv P(y|\theta,g)=\int dx\,P(y|x,\theta)P(x|g)
$$

Assuming that the $n$ outcomes $y$ are conditionally independent given $x$ and that the latent covariates $x$ are independent conditional on the group membership $g$, we can simplify to

\begin{align}
L&=\int dx\,\prod_{i=1}^nP(y_i|\theta,x_i)P(x_i|g_i)\\
&=\prod_{i=1}^n\int dx_i\,P(y_i|\theta,x_i)P(x_i|g_i).
\end{align}

Let's assume that we can draw $m$ samples $\{x^{(1)},\ldots,x^{(m)}\}$ from the conditional distribution $P(x|g)$. Then the likelihood can be approximated by

$$
L\approx\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{m}\sum_{k=1}^mP(y_i|\theta,x_i^{(k)}),
$$

i.e. the integral is approximated by Monte-Carlo integration.

I have applied the above approximation to simulated data and was able to infer the regression coefficients I used to generate the data.

## Method 2 (doesn't work)

The method above works fine assuming conditional independence of $x$ given $g$. But can we do better? Let's approximate the likelihood using Monte-Carlo integration

$$
L\approx \frac{1}{m}\sum_{k=1}^m P(y|\theta,x^{(k)}).
$$

Let's assume independence of $y$ conditional on $x$ and $\theta$ such that

$$
L\approx \frac{1}{m}\sum_{k=1}^m \prod_{i=1}^n P(y_i|\theta,x_i^{(k)}).
$$

Evidently, the two approximations differ in the order of the product and the sum. However, I can't quite get my head around why the second method does not work.

Examples for the inference using either approach can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/tillahoffmann/73097d570b90ef629a930f57933ad351).

Comment: Could you edit the post to tell us in which kind of practical situation this arises?